# como iniciar Primary key desde un numero predeterminado?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Saludos, estoy en la instalación de mi proyecto de grado, es un sistema web 
debería ser instalado en la nube, pero como la institución para el cual realice el proyecto no tiene un servicio de internet y tiene varios oficinas dispersas por la ciudad el sistema esta siendo instalado de forma local en cada oficina dispersa.

Por lo tanto necesito que en cada lugar **los primary keys inicien desde un numero diferente a 1**(esta es mi idea y no estoy seguro si estubiera bien), ya que al final toda la informacion sera centralizada y estoy mas que seguro que al hacer esto me dara error o reemplazara los datos con los ids de otro lugar.

**Tabla empleados**

```
CREATE TABLE `employers` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `items` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, 
  `last_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ci` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` enum('f','m','o') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthday` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `street_live` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthplace` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `cel_phone` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `home_phone` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `office_phone` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `cardex_number` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `photo` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'user.png',
  `position` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `unidad_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE `employers`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `employers_unidad_id_foreign` (`unidad_id`);
```

**Lo que necesito**

> Lugar 1 los ids de empleado inicien desde 1
>   Lugar 2 los ids de empleado inicien desde 5000
>   Lugar 3 los ids de empleado inicien desde 10000
>   Lugar 4 los ids de empleado inicien desde 15000

Espero se haya entendido, y si alguien tuviera otra solución mas practica se lo agradecería.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tú puedes especificar de entrada que tu campo es primary key, que es autoincrement y al final del CREATE TABLE indicas de cuánto tiene que incrementarse.

En el primer caso no indicas nada al final, en los otros casos, por ejemplo, para ´5000`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `employers5000_20170914`  
(
    `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) 
    ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
    AUTO_INCREMENT = 5000
;
```

Veamos una prueba completa.

#### `Código:` <kbd>[`Ver demo en Rextester`](http://rextester.com/YNZ30017)</kbd>

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `employers1_20170914`  
(
    `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) 
    ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
;

INSERT INTO `employers1_20170914` (`name`)
    VALUES
    ('Pedro'),
    ('Santiago'),
    ('Juan')
;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `employers5000_20170914`  
(
    `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) 
    ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
    AUTO_INCREMENT = 5000
; 

INSERT INTO `employers5000_20170914` (`name`)
    VALUES
    ('Pedro-5000'),
    ('Santiago-5000'),
    ('Juan-5000')
;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `employers10000_20170914`  
(
    `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) 
    ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
    AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000
; 

INSERT INTO `employers10000_20170914` (`name`)
    VALUES
    ('Pedro-10000'),
    ('Santiago-10000'),
    ('Juan-10000')
;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `employers15000_20170914`  
(
    `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) 
    ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
    AUTO_INCREMENT = 15000
; 

INSERT INTO `employers15000_20170914` (`name`)
    VALUES
    ('Pedro-15000'),
    ('Santiago-15000'),
    ('Juan-15000')
;

SELECT * FROM `employers1_20170914`;
SELECT * FROM `employers5000_20170914`;
SELECT * FROM `employers10000_20170914`;
SELECT * FROM `employers15000_20170914`;
```

#### `Resultado:`

Empezando en 1

```
id      name
1       Pedro
2       Santiago
3       Juan
```

Empezando en 5000

```
id      name
5000    Pedro-5000
5001    Santiago-5000
5002    Juan-5000
```

Empezando en 10000

```
id      name
10000   Pedro-10000
10001   Santiago-10000
10002   Juan-10000
```

Empezando en 15000

```
id  name
15000   Pedro-15000
15001   Santiago-15000
15002   Juan-15000
```

Answer (score 5):

Estimado,

En la propiedad `IDENTITY` del campo `id` le dices desde que numero quieres que comience a asignar y el incremento del mismo.

Para el Lugar 1 sería:

`id int(10) IDENTITY(1,1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL`

Para el Lugar 2:

`id int(10) IDENTITY(5000,1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL`

Para el Lugar 3:

`id int(10) IDENTITY(10000,1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL`

Y así sucesivamente.

Answer (score 2):

```
`id` int(10) IDENTITY (5000, 1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
```

En este caso le dices que comience desde el id número 5000 y que cada registro se vaya incrementado en 1.

Lo mismo para el resto:

```
`id` int(10) IDENTITY (10000, 1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`id` int(10) IDENTITY (15000, 1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
```